# How to make ActionScript 3 FLA's features remain in HTML5 after converting?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, createjs, flash-cc

I am converting FLA ActionScript 3 games to HTML5 and cord the actions in createJS. My problem is that some of the feature that is in flash do not convert completely to HTML5, and I further go to know those features are as listed in this link; https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/unsupported-features-html5-canvas1.html?PID=3662453.

I need **Filter Feature** to remain in HTML5 so that on a click action the respective object will glow. Please guide me in how to do modifications to make these features remain in HTML5 as well.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You can't always have your cake and eat it too you know...

Comment: @BoltClock the cake is a lie anyway. I'm voting to close this for being unclear. The list includes the glow filter, which means it is supported to some degree.

Comment: Not gonna happen, you want HTML you need to accept its limitation and you need to accept the conversion limitation. If you want a HTML5 app that does what you want you should create it from scratch, if you want to stick with converting from as3 you should accept what you get and be happy about it.

Comment: Thanks @BotMaster. I added an additional layer and converted both glowing and the new layer to a symbol. This resulted in a instance glow  which is not as smooth as flash. Now I am looking for a way to make the make the appearance better by changing the flash file.

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear @null. I am still new to asking questions ans not fluent in English as well.

Answer (score 0):

FlaExporter supports the features you're looking for.  It converts FLA files with ActionScript and Filters to HTML5.

http://www.fla-exporter.com/DoubleClick-HTML5-Ads-With-Adobe-Animate-FlaExporter-Tutorial